# C++:How to generate a list of non-repeated random number

Tags: c++

For instance, generating a list of non-repeated random number from 0 to 51.[0,51]

```
for(int i = 0;i<52;i++)
   {

    //print out 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,....,51.

   }
```

Comment: Is this for homework or for regular work?

Comment: It appears to be for a card game, given that there are 52 items.

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity It is NOT a homework.

Comment: @user1118321 yes, it is!

Comment: @MinGW: there is an aptly named library function called `shuffle` (or `random_shuffle` if you haven't yet gone for c++11)

Comment: @MinGW _'All I need is just a little hint'_ So at least ask for that one in particular and clearly! I don't mind if it's your homework. But you still put your questions in a well defined/accepted format!

Comment: @g-makulik OK. I appreciate your mention,SIR. but according to other people's answers below, I have already figured out the solution.

Comment: @MinGW, I asked because if this is homework professors don't want you using `std::random_shuffle` or `std::shuffle`.  They want you to show that you understand how to implement an algorithmic way of doing it.  So the appropriate answer changes based on whether you just need something functional, or if you need to learn how to design and implement an algorithm.

Comment: Actually, I have two solutions of my problem. I just want to find out more solutions to solve my problem. Low reputation doesn't mean they are homework-posters.

Comment: @MinGW, It's not that you're low rep, it's just the question itself. Homework questions are often quite noticeable, and they're ok as long as the question fits the format and is accepted as useful on the site. Doing some contrived task in a contrived way is often not.

Comment: @MinGW, that's why I was asking.  It wasn't an accusation, it was asking for clarity so I would know how to construct an answer to your question.  Stop being so defensive please.  This entire argument could have been avoided if you put some actual effort into your question in the first place.  Just some food for thought.

Answer (score 3):

Create an `array` or `vector` and randomly shuffle.

```
vector<int> v;
for(int i = 0; i < 52; ++i)
    v.push_back(i);
std::random_shuffle(v.begin(), v.end()); //need #include <algorithm>
```

First random number will be `v[0]`, you have 52 non repeating random numbers

Comment: What exactly you're answering here (whithout being asked for)?

Comment: `std::shuffle` with a proper PRNG would be a bit better if available.

Comment: @chris Aha! The blind leading the lame ...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to shuffle a deck of cards for homework ;)

Here's the code in Python to help you get started:

```
def shuffle(deck):
    for i in xrange(len(deck)):
        rand_index = random.randint(i, len(deck) - 1)
        temp = deck[i]
        deck[i] = deck[rand_index]
        deck[rand_index] = temp
```

Comment: I like that 'phyton-code' thing here ;) ...